# Relative performance and tradeoffs of ROS vs ICE (as middleware)

Tags: ros, performance

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Has anyone done a performance comparison (bandwidth efficiency, congestion handling, latency, ???) between ROS and ICE? Anyone used both enough to give some pros/cons to selecting one or the other as a middleware?

(ROS emphasises the Publish/Subscribe aspect and ICE the RPC aspect but each do both and I'm interested in any 'real' comparison information)

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/48253/relative-performance-and-tradeoffs-of-ros-vs-ice-(as-middleware)/) by [hauptmech](https://answers.ros.org/users/1829/hauptmech/) on ROS Answers with karma: 71 on 2012-11-13

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

As you mention in your question. They emphasize completely different transport paradigms thus it makes 'real' comparisons very hard. It mostly depends on your application and use case, and what your constraints are.

---

Originally posted by [tfoote](https://answers.ros.org/users/3/tfoote/) with karma: 58457 on 2015-06-26

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [hauptmech](https://answers.ros.org/users/1829/hauptmech/) on 2015-11-26**:
I'm guessing you mean transport in the sense of RPC vs PubSub rather than SCTP vs DCCP. What is wrong with comparing ICE RPC with ROS RPC and ICE PubSub with ROS PubSub?